# Does git revert/reset work against cryptolocker and its variants?

Tags: git, virus, git-reset, git-revert

So we have a server that hosts our code that has a possibility of getting the newest crytpo variant. I was wondering if we did a git revert or reset it would remove the encrypted files and we can go on our merry way without needing to restore the whole repo (over a backup file transfer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I don't think doing the reset/revert will be enough and those options aren't really deleting anything, just moving reference pointers around.**

If you have binary files in your repositories history doing a reset/revert may make them unreachable by your HEAD, but those files will still be living somewhere in your .git directory.

You could use [filter-branch](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/) to remove the file if you haven't pushed yet and it only affected someones local client.

But if that file has been pushed to a central repository that your team members are fetching from it will be very hard to guarantee that no-one has that file downloaded.

I would restore the whole repo.

Comment: Sweet thanks it is just a large live site that we are working on the best solution to restore from if the attack did happen.